# How can I connect to an Amazon RDS instance from my Docker image of springboot application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, containers, amazon-rds

Getting below error:

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications
>   link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
>           at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
>           at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
>           at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
>           at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
>           at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
>           at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
>           at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]

Comment: Can you provide the network configuration details for both ECS and RDS instances?

Comment: Can you provide more info like the config, docker run  command you used, dockerfile is any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the exact problem. It has an issue with the security configuration file. Need to allow required port number.